# Why isn't my module class suffix appended to the menu module inside Joomla?

Tags: joomla

When I try to add Module Class Suffix to the menu module, it's not being shown on site.

I placed a custom value into the 'Module Class Suffix' field. There is only one menu component being used. However, the value I specified is not being appended to the classname attribute of the element.

I have cache disabled. Is there anything else I should check for?

I'm using latest stable Joomla 3.0.2

Comment: are you sure you're entering the class suffix in correctly and that it has actually been defined in the CSS?

Comment: i inserted in into the 'Module Class Suffix' field. There is only one menu component being used. Its not appending the classname to the element.

Comment: double check the CSS file for the template to make sure the class has been defined and is the same name. It will most likely be in a file called `modules.css`

Comment: when you say its not being shown - do you mean the class isn't being added or the css changes you've assigned to the class aren't taking effect?

Comment: why was this question closed? Is joomla off topic? css? Im confused.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot vote up, yet - but Mike's comment to his own answer is the solution that is IMO missing from the standard joomla templates (e.g. beez or protostar). Thank you!
To clarify: I copied /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php to my template's html/mod_menu/ directory and added the following near the top:

`<?php $moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')); ?>
  <nav class="navigation<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">`

Right before the

`<?php // The menu class is deprecated. Use nav instead. ?>`

Of course, closed the `<nav>` at the end of the file, too.

(Almost missed the comment, that's why I wanted to vote and now had to post.)

Comment: Is Joomla unwanted here? Would be a good addition at stackexchange - WordPress and Drupal are there, too ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Module Template is not using the class suffix parameter.
In the template file of your module there should be something like:

```
<div class="mymodule<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>">
```

Comment: It is there. /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php  <?php echo $class_sfx;?>

Comment: - is it getting set too? $moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
- maybe there is an module override?